# Seperate address name from number android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am creating an app and i get an Address from geocoder.So I am getting a string that contains the address.My problem is that I want to put the name in a Textview the number in an Edittext(so the client can edit the number) and the city with the postcode to an other Textview.Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate? what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a particular pattern in the Address you get, you can use `String.split()` method of `Java` to extract `tokens` which can then be used individually to fill particular information. [See this example for understanding its working](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/string-split-example-in-java-tutorial.html).

The best approach would be to write a `Regular expression` and group corresponding pieces of information and then getting them back using `Matcher` class.
[This example explains how to get Regular expression's to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863630/regex-for-splitting-a-german-address-into-its-parts).